# “Sorry, Ubuntu * has experienced an internal error.” /usr/bin/compiz

Tags: compiz

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 in VirtualBox with Base OS Windows 7.

The Installation was fine and I did Tick on Download updates and Third Party App. After this it completed installation and Rebooted , Ubuntu load up to Just wallpaper and cursor on the screen. After some time It showed error :

```
“Sorry, Ubuntu 13.10 has experienced an internal error.” /usr/bin/compiz.
```

What to do now please.